# First element of linked list not showing/printing in C

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I trying to add things into a linked list via user input and then print out that list of elements after. However, when I receive the first input, it does it fine, but upon receiving more inputs, it seems like the first element disappears or is not in the linked list. I don't know whats wrong
I'm I adding the elements into the linked list incorrectly?

Here's a sample output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj03v.png)
After "alarm> ..." the alarm_list is different after the two commands as shown by the list [list ...]

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "errors.h"
#define DEBUG

/*
 * The "alarm" structure now contains the time_t (time since the
 * Epoch, in seconds) for each alarm, so that they can be
 * sorted. Storing the requested number of seconds would not be
 * enough, since the "alarm thread" cannot tell how long it has
 * been on the list.
 */
typedef struct alarm_tag {
    struct alarm_tag    *link;
    int                 seconds;
    time_t              time;           /* seconds from EPOCH */
    char                message[128];
    char                req_type[20];   // for the type of request
    int                 alarm_id;       // alarm id
} alarm_t;

pthread_mutex_t alarm_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
alarm_t *alarm_list = NULL;

/*
 * The alarm thread's start routine.
 */
void *alarm_thread (void *arg)
{
    alarm_t *alarm;
    int sleep_time;
    time_t now;
    int status;

    /*
     * Loop forever, processing commands. The alarm thread will
     * be disintegrated when the process exits.
     */
    while (1) {
        status = pthread_mutex_lock (&alarm_mutex);
        if (status != 0)
            err_abort (status, "Lock mutex");
        alarm = alarm_list;

        /*
         * If the alarm list is empty, wait for one second. This
         * allows the main thread to run, and read another
         * command. If the list is not empty, remove the first
         * item. Compute the number of seconds to wait -- if the
         * result is less than 0 (the time has passed), then set
         * the sleep_time to 0.
         */
        if (alarm == NULL)
            sleep_time = 1;
        else {
            alarm_list = alarm->link;
            now = time (NULL);
            if (alarm->time <= now)
                sleep_time = 0;
            else
                sleep_time = alarm->time - now;
#ifdef DEBUG
            printf ("[waiting: %d(%d)\"%s\"]\n", alarm->time,
                sleep_time, alarm->message);
#endif
            }

        /*
         * Unlock the mutex before waiting, so that the main
         * thread can lock it to insert a new alarm request. If
         * the sleep_time is 0, then call sched_yield, giving
         * the main thread a chance to run if it has been
         * readied by user input, without delaying the message
         * if there's no input.
         */
        status = pthread_mutex_unlock (&alarm_mutex);
        if (status != 0)
            err_abort (status, "Unlock mutex");
        if (sleep_time > 0)
            sleep (sleep_time);
        else
            sched_yield ();

        /*
         * If a timer expired, print the message and free the
         * structure.
         */
        if (alarm != NULL) {
            printf ("Alarm(%d): Alarm Expired at %d: Alarm Removed From Alarm List\n", alarm->alarm_id, time(NULL));
            printf ("req_type is: %s\n", alarm->req_type);
            printf("alarm_id: %d\n", alarm->alarm_id);
            printf("alarm seconds: %d\n", alarm->seconds);
            printf("alarm message: %s\n", alarm->message);
            free (alarm);
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int status;
    char line[128];
    alarm_t *alarm, **last, *next;
    pthread_t thread;
    // Use temp variables to store user input
    int tid;
    char treq[20];
    char tmessage[128];
    int tsec;

    status = pthread_create (
        &thread, NULL, alarm_thread, NULL);
    if (status != 0)
        err_abort (status, "Create alarm thread");
    while (1) {
        printf ("alarm> ");
        if (fgets (line, sizeof (line), stdin) == NULL) exit (0);
        if (strlen (line) <= 1) continue;
        alarm = (alarm_t*)malloc (sizeof (alarm_t));
        if (alarm == NULL)
            errno_abort ("Allocate alarm");

        /*
         * Parse input line into alarm request (%20[^(]), alarm id (&d), 
         * seconds (%d), and a message (%128[^\n]), 
         * consisting of up to 128 characters.
         */
        if (sscanf (line, "%20[^(](%d): %d %128[^\n]", treq, &tid, &tsec, tmessage) < 4)
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "Bad command\n");
            free (alarm);
        } 
        else if (strcmp(treq, "Start_Alarm") == 0)    // Start_Alarm request
        {
            status = pthread_mutex_lock (&alarm_mutex);
            if (status != 0)
                err_abort (status, "Lock mutex");
            // Assign temp variables to the new alarm
            alarm->seconds = tsec;
            alarm->time = time (NULL) + alarm->seconds;
            alarm->alarm_id = tid;
            memcpy(alarm->req_type, treq, sizeof alarm->req_type);
            memcpy(alarm->message, tmessage, sizeof alarm->message);

            /*
             * Insert the new alarm into the list of alarms,
             * sorted by alarm id.
             */
            last = &alarm_list;
            next = *last;
            while (next != NULL) {
                if (next->alarm_id >= alarm->alarm_id) {
                    alarm->link = next;
                    *last = alarm;
                    break;
                }
                last = &next->link;
                next = next->link;
            }
            /*
             * If we reached the end of the list, insert the new
             * alarm there. ("next" is NULL, and "last" points
             * to the link field of the last item, or to the
             * list header).
             */
            if (next == NULL) {
                *last = alarm;
                alarm->link = NULL;
            }

            printf("value of last: %p \n", last);
            printf("value of &*last: %p \n", &*last);
            printf("value of *last: %p \n", *last);
            printf("value of &**last: %p \n", &**last);
            printf("value of **last: %p \n", **last);

            printf("value of alarm_list: %p \n", alarm_list);
            printf("value of *alarm_list: %p \n", *alarm_list);
            printf("value of &alarm_list: %p \n", &alarm_list);

            // Print out message that new alarm was added
            printf("Alarm(%d) Inserted by Main Thread(%u) ", alarm->alarm_id, pthread_self()); 
            printf("Into Alarm List at %d: %d %s\n", time(NULL), alarm->seconds, alarm->message);
#ifdef DEBUG
            printf ("[list: ");
            for (next = alarm_list; next != NULL; next = next->link)
                printf ("%d(%d)[\"%s\"] ", next->time, next->time - time (NULL), next->message);
            printf ("]\n");
#endif
            status = pthread_mutex_unlock (&alarm_mutex);
            if (status != 0)
                err_abort (status, "Unlock mutex");
        } else {
            fprintf (stderr, "Bad command, invalid Alarm Request\n");
            free (alarm);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried creating a separate function to insert and sort the element but that made it worse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for your `alarm_t` structures.  Currently you just have `*alarm_t` pointers.  A pointer holds an address of a structure that you need to allocate (and later on free again).

In C, if you don't initialize variables, for example your pointers, they contain garbage.  That things seem to work sometimes in cases like this, is plain luck.

Comment: So do I have to allocate memory for "alarm", "last", "next", and "alarm_list"? But I'm trying to add items into an empty list at first.

Comment: You've added a lot of code in the edit.  Please ruthlessly remove all code that is not needed to show your issue.  All the printing, semaphore stuff, ... don't matter for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

At least this problem:

**Wrong width**

The *width* is the maximum characters to read and save.  After a successful read, a *null character* is appended to the destination.  So the destinatation buffer size needs to be at least 1 more than the width.

```
    int tid;
    char treq[20];
    char tmessage[128];
    int tsec;
    ...    
    // if (sscanf (line, "%20[^(](%d): %d %128[^\n]", treq, &tid, &tsec, tmessage) < 4)
    if (sscanf (line, "%19[^(](%d): %d %127[^\n]", treq, &tid, &tsec, tmessage) < 4)
```

Comment: I'm not having any trouble parsing the input, its just I'm not sure if I'm storing it incorrectly or outputing it incorrectly.